# Layout fluido/responsivo no mínimo 940px e no máximo 1170px com bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Sou um iniciante com Bootstrap e layouts responsivos e encontrei um pequeno obstáculo no desenvolvimento de um layout responsivo utilizando o Bootstrap.
No layout do site, o conteúdo foi criado para ser exibido com no máximo 1170px e no mínimo 940px de largura, devendo ser nesse intervalo, fluído.
No Bootstrap o grid se adapta de 724px e 1170px dependendo do *viewport*, e é nesse ponto que não entendo. É possível determinar com o *viewport* que o layout será responsivo somente entre 940 e 1170 pixels, sendo que em menores que 940px ele se comporte como não responsivo e em maiores que 1170 ele centralize o conteúdo?

Minha estrutura está assim:

```
...
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen">
<link type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
...
```

No estilos.css:

```
/* Desktop maiores */
@media (min-width: 1171px) {
    .container-fluid {
        max-width: 1170px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

O problema é no *viewport*? E como seria o correto?

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode determinar, como em `if, else if` o comportamento para cada tamanho de tela, como até x pixel, entre x e y e maior que y, desta forma:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1171px) {
      //vai o código
}

@media screen and (min-device-width: 940px) and (max-device-width: 1170px) { 
    //vai o codigo
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 939px) {
    //vai o codigo
}
```